# How can I stop Git from inserting carriage returns in local files?

Tags: git, newline, line-breaks, carriage-return, line-endings

I've been trying a lot of different configurations to try to stop Git
from inserting CRs (carriage returns).
I have a local file that has LF (not CRLF) line endings in the source
repo:

```
$ cat -vT  Source/watchr.bat
echo OFF
echo ==========================================================
echo ==========================================================
echo The "watchr" command is deprecated.
echo The new command is sidekick.bat
echo " _
echo "| |
echo "| |_ _   _ _ __   ___
```

Note: no `^M`, so there are no CRs in there.
This is one of about 80 files, so a commit will create massive
needless churn in the Git history.

Now look at the output from `git diff` :

```
$ gd -R Source/watchr.bat
+echo OFF^M
+echo ==========================================================^M
+echo ==========================================================^M
+echo The "watchr" command is deprecated.^M
+echo The new command is sidekick.bat^M
+echo " _                      ^M
+echo "| |                    ^M
+echo "| |_ _   _ _ __   ___ ^M
```

Argh, `^M` on every line. Why? How?

The settings :

```
$ git config --global core.autocrlf
true

$ git config  core.autocrlf
false

$ cat -vT .gitattributes
# Set default behavior to automatically normalize line endings.
* text=
```

Changing the settings to `input` (or `false`) and `auto`
(`.gitattributes`) has no effect.
Git still wants to insert a CR into the `watchr.bat` file.
The `.gitconfig` in my home directory also has `autocrlf = true`.

How do I stop Git from doing this?

Platform: Git version 1.9.5.msysgit.0, Windows 7.

Comment: @Henke https://stackoverflow.com/a/27909336/30946

Comment: Interesting.
As I read [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27909336),
you suggest removing the `.gitattributes` file altogether.
This is in contrast with
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10855862) and
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38677770), which both
_recommend_ using `.gitattributes`.
~ * ~ * ~
For anyone coming here (possibly including my future self)
who has the time to experiment, I would suggest replacing
`* text=auto` with
[`* -crlf`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27370303)
in `.gitattributes` to see what happens.

Comment: I haven't worked in Windows in close to a decade so my experience is very outdated. Maybe it's different now. This question is almost 8 years old.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38017715) is an accurate answer to your question. Just like `dos2unix`, Git can only **guess** whether a file is a text file or not. Both tools make wrong guesses from time to time.
Maybe that's more or less what you write in your answer?
(Windows being bad at guessing from a file's content what type it has.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this was to eliminate `.gitattributes`. I had tried commenting out `* text=auto` in  `.gitattributes` but that apparently wasn't "seen" by git. My coworker eliminated that file, pushed and then I pulled it and suddenly the "add a bunch of CRs everywhere" behavior went away.

I looked for a way to get git to see the newly changed `.gitattributes` (the local edits I made). Couldn't find any git command that would do that, so I had to assume git would check that file anytime it did a diff. Seems that that is not the case.

Perhaps this is a bug in git on Windows (since file watchers are dicey in Windows).

Answer (score 3):

You should try:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

(That is what I recommend in "[Git on Windows (msysgit) - Unix or DOS line termination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1250133/6309)")

Check also the local config:

```
git config core.autocrlf false
```

Make sure you don't have a [`.gitattribute` with a `core.eol` directive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11011701/6309) which could also add `\r\n` eol.

Comment: No dice. Changing global, I still have the ^M at the end of the line. The local config was already set to false.

Comment: Fixed. See my answer.

Comment: So it was a .gitattributes issue after all... +1

Comment: It was. Does that look like a git on Windows bug to you?

Comment: @jcollum I don't think so, not without checking the rest of the `.gitattributes` file, to see if other directives might have been the culprit here.