# Github issue when pulling on Mac OSX

Tags: github

I am using Mac and whenever I pull from github some symbols aren't recognized. For example `§` disappears in the code even though apple has this symbol and it should be recognized. It would be great if someone could help me with this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21472971/what-is-the-purpose-of-text-auto-in-gitattributes

Comment: Text is set to auto already in my .gitattributes, what do i change it to?