# Git * text=auto in the gitattributes file and line endings

Tags: git, gitattributes

Based on this post:
[What is the purpose of `text=auto` in `.gitattributes` file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21472971/what-is-the-purpose-of-text-auto-in-gitattributes)
line endings are converted to **LF** for text files if you have the following in the .gitattributes file:

```
* text=auto
```

I just tested this on a local repository:

```
$ git add -A
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in [bla]/.gitattributes.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in [bla]/.gitignore.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in [bla]/README.md.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in [bla].csproj.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in
```

But there it says the it will convert to **CRLF**. In the post above it says it will convert to **LF** which is not the case in this test.

So it seems that:

```
* text=auto
```

will be converting to the line ending type based on the OS (CRLF for windows and LF for linux). But that is not what is being described here:

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html

Based on below comments/answers it seems that the warning resulting from having this:

```
* text=auto
```

in the .gitattributes file:

```
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in [bla]/README.md.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
```

Actually means that when you do a check-**out** (next time you checkout a file from the repository to you working directory) text files currently with **LF** endings will be converted to have **CRLF**.

The warning does **NOT** address that on check-**in** lines will have **LF** endings which is what the documentation says here:

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html

*Set to string value "auto"
When text is set to "auto", the path is marked for automatic end-of-line normalization. If Git decides that the content is text, its line endings are normalized to LF on checkin.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git replacing LF with CRLF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967370/git-replacing-lf-with-crlf)

Comment: Related yes but not what I am asking for here. Here its about the meaning of a specific warning message and comparing it with the description in the public documentation.

Comment: The warning isn't caused by `text=auto`, but `text=auto` effectively interacts with other options, that you set already before. The other question covers those other options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This message is a bit confusing.

Git will warn you whenever it is not going to round-trip your file identically with your current line ending conversion settings.  This warning is not because Git is going to put CRLFs into the repository (it's not) - this warning comes because the file that Git would checkout is not the same as the file that's currently on your disk.

For whatever reason, the files in your working directory have Unix style line endings (or a mix of Unix and Windows-style).  You should be able to see this with a hex editor.  For example, I have a file with Unix style line endings:

```
C:\Temp>hexdump /C foo
00000000  68 65 6c 6c 6f 21 0a                              |hello!.|
00000007
```

If I add the file to my repository (with `* text=auto` or `core.autocrlf=true`):

```
C:\Temp>git add foo
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in foo.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
```

As git indicates, my file in my current working directory has its original (Unix-style) line endings:

```
C:\Temp>hexdump /C foo
00000000  68 65 6c 6c 6f 21 0a                              |hello!.|
00000007
```

But the file in the repository *also* has Unix style line endings:

```
C:\Temp>git ls-files --stage
100644 4effa19f4f75f846c3229b9dbdbad14eff362f32 0       foo

C:\Temp>git cat-file blob 4effa19 | hexdump /C
00000000  68 65 6c 6c 6f 21 0a                              |hello!.|
00000007
```

But if I ask git to create the file contents *then* it will create a different file - one with CRLF line endings, which is what that warning actually indicates:

```
C:\Temp>del foo

C:\Temp>git checkout -f foo

C:\Temp>hexdump -C foo
00000000  68 65 6c 6c 6f 21 0d 0a                           |hello!..|
00000008
```

So this message is just to warn you that the next checkout of this file will *not* actually match what you have on your disk currently.  In this case, this may be harmless, but this would be critically bad if you were adding a file where the line ending configuration was critical that it matched.

Comment: Ok so that warning is actually addressing when you do a check-out and not related to the check-in rules from the public docs? Seem my edited post.

Comment: Commit and checkout need to be thought of holistically, and your filter and line ending settings apply to both.  This is the appropriate time to warn you, since it's the only time you can take action to correct a mistake.